# quantity words used adverbially to describe the extent of something

Tags: vocabulary, quantifiers

I've noticed the word **plenty** can be used as an adverb:

> We're **plenty** [=very] busy with the work we have already.
>
> It's **plenty** cold outside.
>
> There's **plenty** more where that came from.
>
> The car is **plenty** large enough to fit six people.

I'd like to know whether or not other quantity words can also be used adverbially to describe the extent of something.

Comment: What quantity words? For example. plenty there is very colloquial.

Answer (score 0):

"There's plenty more where that came from" is widely used.  Perhaps the others are local expressions, but in NY I haven't often heard "plenty busy" or "plenty cold."  It's common to say, "it's mighty cold" or "damned cold" and "we're super busy at work."  Americans are prone to making up expressions and new words any way that suits them.  One of my favorites is "ginormous" - a combination of gigantic and enormous.  They quickly become commonplace if they are used in a popular movie.

Comment: I have seen these expressions mostly in texts from the late 19th and early to mid-20th century US, mostly from the Midwest and western parts. But I donot assert that they are used only in those times and places.